# Função Wait do Selenium não captura elemento de carregamento que aparece rapidamente na tela

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Estou com o seguinte Elemento no HTML

```
<div class="atl-container">
   <div class="ui_active_loader">
     ::before
     ::after
   </div>
</div>
```

Representado na seguinte imagem[image: Tabela de resultados sendo carregada]
Na documentação oficial do Selenium existem algumas opções, tentei todas mas a que mais se aproximação do resultado esperado foi a FluentWait, no código abaixo:

```
_wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
{
      PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
};
_wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
```

Onde a cada 1 segundo, por 30 segundos ele verificar a condição do elemento atual, mas acabo recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locatet element{"method":"id","selector":"inputSession"}
```

Estou buscando o elemento via Xpath já que o mesmo não possui Id, e pelo erro, estou entendendo que não foi possível achar a div em questão, já que o carregamento dela é bem rápido, mas por padrões preciso saber se esse Load ja foi concluído para poder prosseguir com a automação.

No local onde esta passando um load, ira aparecer uma tabela com os resultados da pesquisa. Como forçar uma espera até que esse elemento loader se torne invisible ou hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca utilzei o selenium para c#, o que vou sugerir é a partir de um script que possuo que talvez faça o que quer.

Uma maneira de resolver é utilizando a função [`expected_conditions`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=expected%20conditions#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) em combinação com a função [`webDriverWait`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0
#códigos de inicialização e definição do url...
url='https://...'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
#códigos para clicar em elementos

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.ID, "aLoadingBox")))
tabela = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "dtListaEntidade")))
```

Este é um caso bem parecido com o seu, após um clique em um botão, devo esperar o elemento html com id `aLoadingBox` desaparecer (um spinner). Após ele desaparecer eu espero uma tabela html (tag table) com id `'dtListaEntidade'` estar presente no html. A partir deste momento eu faço a raspagem (scrapy) das linhas da tabela.

Estou te passando uma ideia geral de um script que está em prod. Talvez em C# exista alguma função equivalente a estas que possuo em meu código Python.